# How to compare large numbers statically?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, ethereum

I have a large table of Ethereum address like this :

```
address,balance_in_wei
0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2,37523023440555111
0xab7c74abc0c4d48d1bdad5dcb26153fc8780f83e,999999014703265377777771
0x61edcdf5bb737adffe5043706e7c5bb1f1a56eea,820999001231140000000001
0xde0b295669a9fd93d5f28d9ec85e40f4cb697bae,44492
0x07ee55aa48bb72dcc6e9d78256648910de513eca,447526200567627140000001
0x4ddc2d193948926d02f9b1fe9e1daa0718270ed5,428355780858540599597630
0x75ba02c5baf9cc3e9fe01c51df3cb1437e8690d4,335432763520825860248941
0x3bfc20f0b9afcace800d73d2191166ff16540258,306276272361399926202000
0x9a9bed3eb03e386d66f8a29dc67dc29bbb1ccb72,300001020000000000000000
0x059799f2261d37b829c2850cee67b5b975432271,300001000000000000000000
```

And I want only those with a balance above 0.3 Ether which is 30000000000000000000 wei

so I wrote a condition like this one

```
WHERE balance_in_wei>30000000000000000000
```

which gave the following error :

```
Error: Query error: Invalid integer literal: 30000000000000000000
```

As attempting to to declare a static variable for such value does the same thing, how can I perform such comparison ?

Comment: While the address are stored as string, balances are stored as numeric or ɪɴᴛ64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note: `balance_in_wei` should be of data type `NUMERIC` 
If somehow it is `INT64` in your table - it will not work

So, if you are using correct data type your where clause will work as is - and size of your table has nothing to do with that error!

Below is just to **demonstrate and mimic** you sampled data as well as WHERE clause

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT CAST(NULL AS STRING) address, CAST(NULL AS NUMERIC) balance_in_wei UNION ALL
  SELECT '0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2', 37523023440555111 UNION ALL
  SELECT '0xab7c74abc0c4d48d1bdad5dcb26153fc8780f83e', 999999014703265377777771.0 UNION ALL
  SELECT '0x61edcdf5bb737adffe5043706e7c5bb1f1a56eea', 820999001231140000000001.0 UNION ALL
  SELECT '0xde0b295669a9fd93d5f28d9ec85e40f4cb697bae', 44492 UNION ALL
  SELECT '0x07ee55aa48bb72dcc6e9d78256648910de513eca', 447526200567627140000001.0 UNION ALL
  SELECT '0x4ddc2d193948926d02f9b1fe9e1daa0718270ed5', 428355780858540599597630.0 UNION ALL
  SELECT '0x75ba02c5baf9cc3e9fe01c51df3cb1437e8690d4', 335432763520825860248941.0 UNION ALL
  SELECT '0x3bfc20f0b9afcace800d73d2191166ff16540258', 306276272361399926202000.0 UNION ALL
  SELECT '0x9a9bed3eb03e386d66f8a29dc67dc29bbb1ccb72', 300001020000000000000000.0 UNION ALL
  SELECT '0x059799f2261d37b829c2850cee67b5b975432271', 300001000000000000000000.0 
)
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE balance_in_wei > 400001000000000000000000.0
```

with output

[image]

Comment: I told large table. What I gave in my question is only an example. There are billions address.

Comment: number of rows has nothing to do with your problem, the example I use in my answer is just to show that it will work if you using correct data type!

Comment: Ok, I forgot to add 2 0 in my question which is why your answer works.

Comment: Oh, I see what happened. See update in my answer - I added even more zeroes. Important is to add `.0` to the end of that number so BQ engine is not thinking that it is INT64 but rather threat it as NUMERIC